# ASP.NET MVC3 Posting form back to same action

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, parameters, routes

I have an action in my HomeController (to keep it simple):

```
[HttpGet]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyOwnViewModel viewModel)
{
    // do some stuff with the viewmodel and return it to the view.
    // Selected values should be preserved inside the viewModel

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

And I want this action to be called whenever I go to the url /Home/MyAction. It complains that it can't find a MyAction method on the HomeController and I suspect it is because of the viewModel parameter.

Is there any way to work around this? I would expect the viewModel parameter to just be null.

Comment: Not sure the value of both HttpGet and HttpPost filters on the method. What happens when they are removed? Does your MyOwnViewModel have a default constructor? Does the action get called if you define it with no parameters?

Comment: Also, are you using razor and specifying your viewmodel using @model declaration?

Comment: @Zootius, a default constructor apparently does not matter. It is however crucial to remove the [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] as you mentioned. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @Zootius, could you post your findings as an answer? I can't find a suitable one yet and you deserve the credit. If not I will add one myself in a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in this case is to remove one or both of the **[HttpGet]** and **[HttpPost]** action filters.

For the edification of others, it is okay to have an action method that accepts a model parameter, with no alternative parameterless version of the method, as long as the model class has a public default constructor.

In such circumstances, the MVC ModelBinder will generate an empty instance of the model class for you.

Look into the **IModelBinder** interface for more information on custom model binding.

Answer (score 0):

You need one action with none parameter to start it from URL

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{

    return View();
}
```

And use the one you already have to handle the submitted action (this is where `HttpGet` or `HttpPost` attribute applied for) from that view so you will have `viewModel` by then.

Comment: That's not correct. You don't *need* a parameterless action method. As long as the class you pass has a default constructor, and is of the type specified in your View, MVC will create an instance for you.

Comment: @Zootius, I was just saying, OP should whether pass the parameter or use a none parameter method to start with. Or are you saying something else?

Comment: @Zootius is right, you don't need a parameterless action method. You just can't specify more than one HttpVerb attributes.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, I don't know how will and why should you pass your own view model to your action by visiting a URl, but regading your mentioned scenario, I will try to help you fix the missing action behavior and the way to get it discoverable by ASP.NET MVC.

You are correct, because of your `viewModel` parameter, the default route of MVC3 will not find this action, so you have to define a new route to match with your controller action.

consider the following code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
             "SearchRoute1",                                              // Route name
             "MyAction/{viewModel}",                             // URL with parameters
             new { controller = "Home", action = "MyAction", viewModel = "" }  // Parameter defaults

         );
```

you will define something like this inside your `Global.ASAX` file, specifically inside `RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)` method,
so the routing table of your app be aware of your action method, then you can handle the request as normal.

let me know if this helped you, thanks.

Comment: That's not correct. You don't *need* a parameterless action method. As long as the class you pass has a default constructor, and is of the type specified in your View, MVC will create an instance for you.

Comment: what he is trying to call is an action with a parameter, and what he is actually calling is the default action that MVC3 will generate like you said for this call, but not for the parameterless one, and my answer is not including any code for parameterless actions. kindly correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The problem is we don't yet know enough about the OP's context. I'm assuming there is no definition of MyAction that takes no parameters, in which case the **MyAction(MyOwnViewModel viewModel)** method *should* get called, even if no model is being passed to it.
.

Comment: as for my personal expreience, if your URL doesn't match with the default route which is: cotroller/action/{id} id:optional, it won't get called.
that's why you will need to define a route to match your URL to your desired action.

Comment: I've tried defining this route as you suggest Mohammed but it didn't work. I even specified it so that viewModel is an optional parameter in the url but that didn't work either. The solution is to just remove the two HttpVerbs attributes. The modelbinder will create an instance of the viewmodel.

Comment: nice that you figured out the solution. glade to hear that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have one `ActionResult` with two differing HTTP methods. You need to use overloads...

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
     return View(new MyViewModel());
}
```

And

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel model)
{
     // Do your stuff...
     return View(model);
}
```

Comment: You're right, I just think your wording is off. You can both do POST and GET to the same action. But you can't specify this using the attributes. It only works if you remove the GET and POST attributes.

Comment: You know, I wasn't sure how to word it! I prefer this way as, for me, it is easier to read.